# applescript droplet to insert text in safari

Tags: safari, applescript

I have created a droplet that reads a textfile and gives the content to clipboard:

```
on open theFile
open for access theFile
set fileContents to (read theFile)
close access theFile
return fileContents
set the clipboard to fileContents
end open
```

But i am looking for some code to take this contents from clipboard
and insert it into the current field of the frontmost window of safari.

For this purpose i found some code used in an automator action that 
simulates somehow the keystrokes of cmd+v:

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
    return input
end tell
end run
```

My problem is how to put these two things together.
At the end the droplet should work this way:

- drop textfile on droplet
- insert content of textfile in active field of frontmost safari window.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the job done for you.

I had the code keystroke a variable so you do not have to mess around with the clipboard and risk accidentally entering the wrong data.

```
on open the_file
    set the_file_Contents to (read the_file)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke the_file_Contents
        end tell
    end tell
end open
```

If you wanted the code to use the clipboard still (more efficient for large text files), the code would look like this.

```
on open the_file
    set the clipboard to (read the_file)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "v" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end open
```